# Connect Power BI with azure DevOps on premise

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

We have TFS 2019 installed on premise, want to create PowerBI reports based on analytics Views that are already predefined in TFS. Selecting GetData in PowerBI yields a login screen with collection URL and Team Project. We entered TFS sever name in URL connection and the Team Project respectively, getting an error "invalid account". Prior to this PowerBI asked for Login, logged in with my microsoft user. Can u please advise how to connect Power BI to a TFS on premise, we didn't find helpful material searching for it on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually what worked was full URL of the collection in the first field and name of team proejct in the second field.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Can u please advise how to connect Power BI to a TFS on premise, we
>   didn't find helpful material searching for it on the internet.

Assuming you have Power BI Desktop in MachineA. Now you need to make sure:

1.The Azure Devops Server is running and you can login the web portal of Azure Devops Server(once called TFS) in MachineA's browser:

[image]

2.The `Analytics View` option is enabled and you have access to view/edit them:

[image]

3.In Power BI Desktop: For on-premise Azure Devops Server, the `Collection Url` shoule be the team collection url instead of simple ServerName or OrgName:

[image]

The Team Project name is one of your project name. For me I have Project `ForTest` in organization `Test`. And my full url of the project is: `http://xxx/Test/ForTest/`. So I enter `http://xxx/Test/` for `Collection Url` and `ForTest`(simple name of team project !!) for `Team Project`, then it works well to connect to the server:

[image]

Ps: I use Azure Devops Server 2019 Update1(1.1) and latest Power BI Desktop downloaded from Microsoft Store.

Hope my steps make some help for you :)

Comment: @moital  The input of second textbox should be simple `test1`(simple project name) instead of whole URL.

Answer (score 0):

When the login window appears which asking for Account Name to connect TFS, you need to write only name of the account (beginning name of visualtstudio.com) and write specific project name or * if you want to get data for all existing projects.

Comment: Thank u for your response. In our case, Azure Dev Ops as mentioned is installed on premise i.e. on an internal server, Your answer applies only when connected to Azure Dev Ops on cloud i.e. visual studio online. Can u pls advise as per on premise ?

Comment: Do you choose Azure Devops Server Connector as shown here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-november-2018-feature-summary/#devOps  ?

Comment: Yes indeed. I choose Azure Devops Server Connector